# Custom Google Maps Marker for iOS (GMSMarker)

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to create an custom marker for Google Map, but my code is giving me a weird view with space, as the image bellow:

What is that white view? How to remove it? It was supposed to be only the red one!

```
-(UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoContents:(GMSMarker *)marker{
    UIView *infoView = [UIView new];
    infoView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 192);
    // Setting the bg as red just to illustrate
    infoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return infoView;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be a bit rusty but isn't that the wrong function?

There is a markerInfoWindow and a markerInfoContents (which you are using).
The window is the whole thing whereas the contents is a view, which will be placed within the default info window frame

take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p?hl=fa#a961e81669891377c9ebee752ce53340f)

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this white background is that you are using a wrong delegate method. Replace your code with this one:

```
-(UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker{
    UIView *infoView = [UIView new];
    infoView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 192);
    // Setting the bg as red just to illustrate
    infoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return infoView;
}
```